# How can I calculate the number of deductions I should use?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-w-4

Recently I've been trying to adjust my W-4 so that I overpay  the government less (get a smaller tax return).  How can I calculate the number of my deductions based on my income and family status, charitable giving, etc to arrive at the minimal overpayment?

Comment: There's a worksheet on the form, can't you use it?

Comment: @littleadv I haven't filled out the paper one in a long time, didn't remember that.

Comment: Ha! @C.Ross - the article I cited begins "You see a W-4 recently? Do you even remember what Form W-4 is? It’s possible that you filled out this form and gave it to your employer years, perhaps decades ago, and never gave it a second thought." I don't remember the last time I saw the form in the wild.

Answer (score 4):

A W4 allowance is like saying "don't tax $3800 on me, bro."
So, if you are in the 25% bracket, raising it by 1 will have you pay $950 less in a year. 15% bracket? The same extra allowance lowers tax withheld by $540.

An [article I wrote](http://blogs.hrblock.com/2013/01/14/how-to-change-your-w-4-withholding-to-maximize-your-tax-refund/) goes into some depth on the process.